# How to load images from dynamic src in angular2 and webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using angular2 and webpack2 in my project.

My co-workers start the project from Angular2 QuickStart, and then I move it to Webpack environment.

I use `html-loader` to load components templats and use `url-loader` to extract images and fonts:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader'
},
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    use: 'url-loader?limit=1000&name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
},
```

The templates are like this:

```
<section class="creation-mobile">
    <img src="../../../images/camera/cn/mobile/creation.jpg" alt="" class="img-cn">
    <img src="../../../images/camera/en/mobile/creation.jpg" alt="" class="img-en">
</section>
```

When I build it, Webpack can find the images and export them into `asstes/`.

It works fine until I meet templates like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]" class="item{{i}} m1-view">
    <div class="{{lang}}-video-view">
        <img src="../../../images/os/{{lang}}/medium/one-step{{i}}{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}.jpg">
        <video class="video-medium" preload="auto" src="../../../videos/os/{{lang}}/medium/one-step-{{i}}{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}.mp4" [video-play]="onestepVideoState[i-1]"></video>
        <img src="../../../images/os/{{lang}}/large/one-step{{i}}{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}.jpg">
        <video class="video-large" preload="auto" src="../../../videos/os/{{lang}}/large/one-step-{{i}}{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}.mp4" [video-play]="onestepVideoState[i-1]"></video>
    </div>
    <a class="replay" [innerHTML]="os.replay.title" [ngClass]="{'active': onestepReplayState[i-1]}" (click)="onestepReplay(i-1)"></a>
</li>
```

The src like `../../../images/os/{{lang}}/medium/one-step{{i}}{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}.jpg` contains `{{lang}}` and `{{i}}` and `{{deviceRatio == 1?'':'@2x'}}` to fetch different resources， and `url-loader` can not resolve this kind of url.

We have to spread out `*ngFor` and use `ngif`， write plenty of `<img>` tag to import images.

Are there some ways to load this kind of urls in angular2 and webpack?

**Add1**: sorry to forget to declare, `lang` and `deviceRatio` are depend on the browser environment, so the value is not sure when build. the value of `lang` would be one of `cn` and `en`， so we want to load both `../../../images/os/en/medium/..xxx.jpg` and `../../../images/os/cn/medium/..xxx.jpg` to the final dist directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selectively exclude dynamic image paths from webpack with angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205980/selectively-exclude-dynamic-image-paths-from-webpack-with-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build setup you could require the images upfront using `require.context` in the JS file.

```
function importAll (r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}
var modules = importAll(require.context(directory, useSubdirectories = true, regExp = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/));
```

What you do is - require the folder with the images recursively and they will be available in desired locations.
See more here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context